# How to redirect new page with a session message on successful laravel dropzone file upload?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, session, dropzone.js

I use laravel & DropZone to upload file. I want to redirect with a Session message after successful file upload.
my js code is here:

```
 var baseUrl = "{{ url('/') }}";

            Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
             var myDropzone = new Dropzone("form#dropzoneFileUpload", { 
                 url: baseUrl+"/dropzone/uploadFiles",
             });
             Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
                paramName: "file", 
                maxFilesize: 2, // MB
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                accept: function(file, done) {

                },
              };
```

here is my controller code:

```
$upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $fileName); 
        if ($upload_success) {
             \Session::put('success','Uploded successfully.');
            return redirect()->intend('/media');
            //return Response::json('success', 200);
        } else {
            return Response::json('error', 400);
        }
```

how can i use this session message & redirect to another page? This code is not working :

```
 \Session::put('success','Uploded successfully.');
                return redirect()->intend('/media');
```

Comment: is upload and redirect working?

Comment: no. nothing happened, just file uploaded.

Comment: do you use ajax to make the upload?

Comment: no i did not use ajax

Comment: strange. if you can upload you should get the redirect or the json error

Comment: I have no idea, its just upload file, even page is not also refreshed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141371/discussion-between-fsuuaas-and-sam12).

Answer (score 0):

Add `with()` to redirect instead of call Session class

```
return redirect()->intend('/media')->with('success', 'Uploded successfully');
```

Comment: does not redirecting. but if i check Developer Console (Network Tab) here show Request URL:http://localhost:8000/media & Preview tab shown Success message

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your controller import the `Session` class:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

Inside your method:

```
Session::flash('success','here goes your message!');
return redirect('redirect_path');
```

In view file:

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ Session::get('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```